# Export org-mode file to .txt, with my specification

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My org structure is

```
* main heading [0%]
** TODO heading 2 [0%]
*** TODO heading 3 [0%]
**** TODO heading 4 [0%]
***** TODO heading 5 [66%]
****** DONE heading 6
       some content here
****** DONE heading 6 (sibling 2)                                :not:export:
       some other content here
****** TODO heading 6 (sibling 3)
*** TODO heading 3 (sibling 2)
*** TODO heading 3 (sibling 3)
*** TODO heading 3 (sibling 5)
```

---

1. I need to export DONE state headings to ‘filename.txt’ file with
   heading and content only. Not TODO, DONE, ‘*’s and [0%] of
   completion of task.
2. If I add :not-export: to heading example ‘heading 6 (sibling 2)’,
   ‘filename.txt’ needs to have heading only not it’s content.
3. ‘heading 6’ and ‘heading 6 (sibling 2)‘ are sharing same parents so
   should not duplicate in exported file.
4. Headings may be 6 levels deeper, but not necessary
5. ‘filename.txt’ needs to open in one of the ‘windows’ OS programs (ex:
   Balabolka)

Ex: Values or data-types

```
Primitive
    String
        char At
        char Code At
        from Char Code
        concat
        index Of
    Boolean
    Undefined
    Null
Object or Reference type
    Reg Ex
        test
        match
        exec
    Array
```

**What I am doing here?**

I am trying to lean programming languages, I need to
read, understand, /record/, listen and recollect, it’s vocabulary and
grammar.

Org-mode helps me to lean and take a notes, but the /record/ part I
want, I have another program called ‘Balabolka’ to do that.

I just need ‘.txt’ file version of my org-mode file with my own
formating specified above.

Your different MVP can always be welcome.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: For your info, I know ‘C-c C-e t u’, it exports as plan ‘.txt’ file.